# c# DataSet Cannot make this change because constraints are enforced on relation XXX, and changing this value will strand child rows

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a DataSet with few tables, 2 of them are related in Conatraint in the XSD file.

When I save (update with the data adapter) the parent table I get this error:

```
Cannot make this change because constraints are enforced on relation XXX, and changing this value will strand child rows.
```

XXX is the relation in the XSD file.

I simply don't understand what is this, I've tried google but nothing.

The parent table id is connected with FK to a column in the child table and saving the parent table should update the child.

I don't understand this error, please help.

EDIT:

The code that creates new row in the child table MyDataSet.Patient_IVFOocytesFreezeOocytesInGroups:

```
                    // connect the oocytes with a group
                    IVFOocyteManagerDataset.Patient_IVFOocytesFreezeOocytesInGroupsRow newgrouprow = MyDataSet.Patient_IVFOocytesFreezeOocytesInGroups.NewPatient_IVFOocytesFreezeOocytesInGroupsRow();

                    if (selectedStraws.Count == 1)
                    {
                        int g = MyDataSet.Patient_IVFOocytesFreezeStraw.Where(x => x.IsSelecetd == true).Select(x => x.group_id).FirstOrDefault();
                        newgrouprow.group_id = MyDataSet.Patient_IVFOocytesFreezeGroups.Where(x => x.group_id == g).Select(x => x.group_id).SingleOrDefault();

                        OocyteStraws.Rows[i].StrawDisplayId = MyDataSet.Patient_IVFOocytesFreezeStraw.Where(x => x.IsSelecetd == true).Select(x => x.display_id).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    else
                    {                           
                        OocyteStraws.Rows[i].StrawDisplayId = -1;
                        newgrouprow.group_id = selectedStraws.Select(x => x.group_id).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
```

MyDataSet.Patient_IVFOocytesFreezeGroups is the parent table.

Comment: It looks like you imported an xml file into a datatable and the results do not match the schema (xsd).  The values you inserted into he datatable are not matching the schema.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after few hours I found the answer:

In the DataSet Designer, the reltaion wasn't Cascade. Tha'ts all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the ID value on the parent table or is it an auto generated identity?  You really shouldn't be changing it in the update.

Can you post your data models and the updating code that you are using so that it is easier to see what is going on?

Comment: I'm not touching the id it is auto generated, I only assing it to the child row

Comment: Have you setup virtual properties for the related table objects? I have seen EF complain like this before when trying to set the id of a foreign key directly.  It tends to prefer that you setup your model with the FK and virtual object property and then set the object value as opposed to the id itself.  If you can post your data models, I can give you an example of this.

Comment: I'm using mvvm so the datamodels are the dataset tables. I'm not using EF